# How do I print the lists of all the indices within defaultdict in Python 3?

Tags: python, defaultdict

I defined a defaultdict as follows:

```
results=defaultdict(list)
```

In a for loop that reads through each line in my dictionary file, I generate a tempWordObject that contains the original word (originalWord), its alphabetized version (azWord), and the length of the word (wLength). I then append the object to a list based on its length:

```
results[tempWordObject.wLength].append(tempWordObject)
```

So, what I should end up with, is a defaultdict called results that has lists of words based on their lengths. So, for example, results[4] should contain all 4 letter words in a list. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding what is happening.

What I'm trying to do (for testing purposes and to generate results later) is print all lists I have in defaultdict after I'm done reading through the file. So, it will print the list of word objects defaultdict[1] in the first line, the list of word objects in defaultdict[2] in the second line, etc. I would also like to be able to print only a specific parameter when I do this.

If it's of any help, I will have the length of the longest word (maxL) once the loop is done.

I think part of the reason I couldn't get this working is due to me misunderstanding how ever is stored in defaultdict and/or how I'm storing it. An explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the keys, in sorted order:

```
for length in sorted(results):
    print length, [t.originalWord for t in results[length]]
```

A `defaultdict` is still a dictionary; `sorted(results)` returns a list of all the keys in that dictionary, sorted. Using each key you can then access the stored lists of your special objects again, with `results[length]`. The list comprehension merely pulls out each `originalWord` attribute from those objects.

Comment: Because `defaultdict` is still a [mapping](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), just like `dict`.

Comment: My main problem is that it keeps printing like this, for example: 7 [<__main__.word object at 0x01D86210>, <__main__.word object at 0x01D97450>, <__main__.word object at 0x01D974D0>, <__main__.word object at 0x01D97550>]

Comment: So then iterate those lists and access them appropriately.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by iterating through the lists. Could you please expand on that and/or provide an example?

Comment: @Michi: I added a list comprehension for you pulling out the original words for you.

Comment: @Martijn - thanks! I'm actually "not allowed" to use the built in sorting functions so I did this and it seemed to work just as well:
for length in results:
    print (length, [t.originalWord for t in results[length]])
However, I'm still a little confused about the syntax. Where is "length" obtained and what is "t" in the loop? I just started learning Python a few days ago, so I'm very much a beginner.

Comment: `length` is just the name I picked for the `for` loop target. Each iteration assigns the next key from `results` to it. Same for `t` in the list comp. Pick any name you like for it, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters also one more question. When I ran it for my actual dictionary (as opposed to the test run), I noticed that after it print the list of words of length of 14, it skipped 2 lines (no words are of length 15/16) and jumped to 17. However, this didn't happen between 23 and 45 (no words of length 23 to 44). Why does this happen?

Comment: You mean it printed `15 []` then `16 []`? Or `14 [word, word<2 blank lines>]` then `17 []`?

Comment: The empty lists just mean you tried to see if `results[15]` exists elsewhere in your code or test session. The blanks are newlines in your strings; make sure you strip all whitespace properly when reading from a file.

Comment: It only leaves blanks for lines 15 and 16. However, it does not create blanks between 23 and 45. Right now it prints 14 [list of words], newline, newline, 17 [list of words] ... 23 [list of words], 45 [list of words]. So, it's inconsistent. All of my strings have already been dealt with using .strip('\r\n'.

Comment: Maybe this screenshot will help make sense of what I'm trying to convey: http://i.imgur.com/rFzF6C5.png Would you like me to post my code?

Comment: I have *no idea* what causes that. That could make an interesting *new* question. This question has been answered; don't post your new puzzle / enigma / interesting problem here.

Comment: I made a new question but in the process I discovered that those are not spaces. The code you provided simply skips all the words 15 and 16 characters long.